# How do I grep in vim netrw?

Tags: vim, grep, netrw

How do I do a grep in netrw in Vim? ctrl-p can be used in this way, is there a similar plugin for grep?

E.g., when I'm in a directory, I want a list of files containing this or that keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Netrw *does* have "that feature"; see :help netrw-star. You can do for instance `:Explore */filepath` or more generally use one of the patterns below:

```
*/filepath   files in current directory which satisfy filepath
**/filepath  files in current directory or below which satisfy the
            file pattern
*//pattern  files in the current directory which contain the
            pattern (vimgrep is used)
**//pattern files in the current directory or below which contain
            the pattern (vimgrep is used)
```

Use `:Pexplore` and `:Nexplore` to go to the previous/next matching file (and `@:` to repeat the chosen command); hit `<cr>` to enter the file.

Answer (score 2):

Netrw doesn't have that feature.

You can use the built-in `:vimgrep`:

```
:vim foo * | cw
```

or `:grep`, that uses your external `grep` by default or whatever alternative program (like `ack` or `ag`) via the `grepprg` option:

```
:grep foo * | cw
```

See `:help :grep`, `:help :vimgrep` and `:help :cwindow`.

Comment: Won't that search in my pwd instead of the netrw dir I'm in?

Comment: `let netrw_keepdir = 0` keeps netrw's browsing dir and Vim's current dir in sync. You can also keep it at its default value and press `c`. See `:help netrw-c`.

Comment: You can search a directory with `:vimgrep` like so: `:vim foo dir/*` and recursively like: `:vim foo dir/**`. I also suggest you take a look at [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) , [Ag the Silver Surfer](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), or [git grep](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html) as they are typically more performant than regular grep and certainly `:vimgrep`